# how convert a string ('No. 10') to a number 10 and ('18.12') to 18.12 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

This is the problem:

Write a function parseFirstInt that takes a string and returns the first integer present in the string. If the string does not contain an integer, you should get NaN. parseFirstInt('No. 10') should return 10 and parseFirstInt('Babylon') should return NaN.

i use parseFloat and parseInt but Not solve it.

my code is here:

```
        parseFirstInt = function(str){
          var a = str.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");
          var b = parseFloat(a);
          return b;
           } 

          //parseFirstInt('No. 10') return 10
          //BUT parseFirstInt('18.12') return 1812
```

Comment: You're stripping out all non-digit characters, which would include the `.` in "18.12".

Comment: Elaborate on your intentions related to "integer". I know what an integer is, but the wording of the question does not sound, like you want to deal with BigInt, other number notations, etc. More specifically, what are the results for e.g. `"123456789012345678"`, `"011"`, `"3e14"`, `"0x14"`, `"-0"`, `"18.12"`, ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use regx /(\d)+/g to get numbers. See below code

var str = "No. 10";
alert(Number(str.match(/(\d)+/g)[0]));

Answer (score -2):

I hope it helps,

```
function parseFirstInt(str){
const reg = RegExp(/\d+/g);
let arr = reg.exec(str);
 if(arr == null){
    return NaN;
 }

 return arr[0];
 }

  var res = parseFirstInt("India9Delhi78Asia67");
  console.log(res); // 9
```